# Interrupting an infinitely running Pyplot loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, keyboardinterrupt

I need to implement a real time plot which needs to run indefinitely until I interrupt it with a keypress or a cntrl C.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import psutil
import time


plt.plot()

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(12, 6)  # width and height in inches

fig.show()
i=1
x, y = [], []
x_scale = 30

while True:

    if len(x) > x_scale:
        x.pop(0)
        y.pop(0)
    x.append(i)
    y.append(psutil.cpu_percent())
    plt.plot(x,y, color = 'b')
    
    fig.canvas.draw()

    plt.ylabel('CPU (%)')
    plt.xlabel('TIME (ds)')
    plt.xlim(left=i-x_scale, right=i)
    plt.ylim(top = 100, bottom = 0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    i += 1
```

This code may not be optimal since I am still learning Matplotlib but it is doing what I want.( Monitoring psutils is only temporary.) My problem is, I am unable to interrupt the plotting even with a cntrl C. Only thing that works is cntrl+alt+delete which in Linux is logging me out.

Any suggestions please?

xuraax

Answer (score 0):

I used `plt.waitforbuttonpress()` instead of `time.sleep()`. for solving the *not responding* window and breaking on key interrupt.
I hope you see this helpful:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import psutil


plt.plot()

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(12, 6)  # width and height in inches

fig.show()
i = 1
x, y = [], []
x_scale = 30

while True:
    if len(x) > x_scale:
        x.pop(0)
        y.pop(0)
    x.append(i)
    y.append(psutil.cpu_percent())
    plt.plot(x, y, color='b')

    fig.canvas.draw()

    plt.ylabel('CPU (%)')
    plt.xlabel('TIME (ds)')
    plt.xlim(left=i - x_scale, right=i)
    plt.ylim(top=100, bottom=0)
    i += 1
    if plt.waitforbuttonpress(0.1): break # this will wait 0.1 seconds for your keypress and if pressed, it breaks out of the loop
    # and you simply can close the plot window
```

Comment: @xuraax accepting this answer would be nice. thanks :)

Comment: Oooops!!! Very sorry about that. A very belated thank you for your suggestion.